# Using tcpdump on displayed TCP data

Tags: tcp, tcpdump

If

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -X
```

gives me

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
16:16:11.837543 IP cnt62-i386.gci.xxxx.org.ssh > jazz.gci.xxxx.org.49283: Flags [P.], seq 291677310:291677502, ack 4122992911, win 1002, options [nop,nop,TS val 2421999802 ecr 2194736071], length 192
        0x0000:  4510 00f4 7f77 4000 4006 7f84 ac16 f184  E....w@.@.......
        0x0010:  ac16 f146 0016 c083 1162 a47e f5bf e10f  ...F.....b.~....
...
```

how do I filter on the displayed data (eg the initial hex 45 value)?

In particular,

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -X 'tcp[0]=0x45'
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -X 'tcp[12]=0x45'
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -X 'tcp[14]=0x45'
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -X 'tcp[20]=0x45'
```

all give no matches (using various offsets from randomly and cluelessly googling around).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter using `ip` instead of `tcp`. For your example:

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -X 'ip[0] = 0x45'
```

Comment: ah!  perfect.  so where does tcp[0] start in that?  is there an offset in tcp i can use, or is tcp only for the header?  thanks!  or am i confused - was that not a tcp packet?

Comment: The "5" in "45" is the IP header length, in 4-byte units, so that's 20 bytes.  Therefore, `tcp[0]` is 20 bytes after `ip[0]`, and thus it's 0x00, followed by 0x16, followed by 0xc0, followed by 0x83.  That's the TCP ***HEADER***, however, not the TCP ***PAYLOAD***, so if you want to filter on the data being transported over TCP, you have to skip past the TCP header (which is variable-length, just as is the IP header).

Comment: thanks.  it turns out i did have a bunch of that (although i wasn't very confident of it).  but i was missing the variable length tcp header (i am actually searching for something in the tcp payload, and with the above everything now makes sense).